# Reveal.JS - How to specify eventListener on a specific fragment?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, addeventlistener, reveal.js

I am creating a reveal.js presentation. I wish to trigger some changes to the dom when a specific fragment is shown. The [documentation](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/#fragment-events) shows a generic eventListener that that executes when the first fragment on a page is shown.

I want to trigger an event that adds a class('invis') to the first fragment on the page, only when the third fragment is shown. Coming up lost. Please see the code examples below:

```
<section data-transition="fade" data-background="images/assets/Slide15/Slide15-bg.png">
  <div class="f-left fragment roll-in" id="bp30"></div>
  <div class="f-left fragment roll-in" id="bp31"></div>
  <div class="f-left fragment roll-in" id="bp32"></div>
  <aside></aside>
</section>
```

and the script:

```
Reveal.addEventListener( 'fragmentshown', function( event ) { 
 document.getElementById('bp30').classList.add("invis");
} );
Reveal.addEventListener( 'fragmenthidden', function( event ) {
 document.getElementById('bp30').classList.remove("invis");
} );
```

This adds the "invis" class to the the first fragment on the slide when the first fragment is shown. Is it possible to specify that we are listening for the 3rd fragment to be shown before adding the class to the first fragment?

Answer (score 2):

So the best solution does not involve the addEventListener at all. I was thinking way to hard.

The correct answer in this case is to nest the fragment that needs to be removed or hidden, into another fragment that fades out. Then we use the Fragment Index data attachment to specify the order in which we want these fragments to animate.

You can trigger multiple fragments to animate in/out on the same step with the index.

See updated code below:

```
<section data-transition="fade" data-background="images/assets/Slide15/Slide15-bg.png">
 <span class="fragment fade-out" data-fragment-index="3">
  <div class="f-left fragment roll-in" data-fragment-index="1" id="bp30"></div>
 </span>
  <div class="f-left fragment roll-in" data-fragment-index="2" id="bp31"></div>
  <div class="f-left fragment roll-in" data-fragment-index="3" id="bp32"></div>
  <aside></aside>
</section>
```

As you can see, I nest the first fragment into a span and set it as a fragment that will animate out with a fade. I set the fragment index for each fragment. The first fragment step will roll-in #bp30, the second step will roll-in #bp31. Because I have set the index for the span fragment to 3, as well as the span index for #bp32 to 3. This way, they execute on the same step.

I have #bp32 positioned on top of #bp30 with negative margin-top value. So, on the third step, #bp30 will fade outat the same time that #bp32 rolls in.

Answer (score 1):

The document doesn't indicate that it can listen on a particular element. It seems that it's up to you to check the element of the fragment being triggered is the one you want to modify.

```
Reveal.addEventListener( 'fragmentshown', function( event ) { 
    if(event.fragment.id === 'bp30') { 
        event.fragment.classList.add("invis");
    }
} );
Reveal.addEventListener( 'fragmenthidden', function( event ) {
    if(event.fragment.id === 'bp30') { 
        event.fragment.classList.remove("invis");
    }
} );
```